# Classic Circle and Adjacent Arrangement Problem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given: A circle with nine distinct positive integers. n is a fixed positive integer.

So these positive integers are arranged in the circle in such a way that the product of any selected two NON-ADJACENT numbers in the circle is a multiple of n. The product of two ADJACENT numbers in the circle is NOT a multiple of n. What is the smallest posible value for n.

Comment: I mean what I wrote. What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: This question comes from the current USAMTS Round 3 problem set ([problem 4](http://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_3.pdf)). This question will remain locked until after the submission deadline of 19 Jan 2015.

Comment: This was a problem asked during an open mathematical competition for the purposes of gaining an unnatural and unfair advantage. It had been locked and hidden. Although it is now unlocked, since the competition has passed, this is abusive and bad; and I downvoted. It is unfortunate, as the question is pleasant and the answer good.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do (most of) the case of four numbers, and leave the case of nine numbers as an exercise.

I claim that with four numbers, the smallest $n$ is $2\times3\times5\times7=210$.

First, let's see that $210$ is a legitimate value of $n$; let the four numbers, in order around the circle, be $6,15,35,14$. Then the non-adjacent numbers are $6$ and $35$, product $210$, and $15$ and $14$, product $210$, so both divisible by $210$. The adjacent pairs are $6\times15=90$, $15\times35=525$, $35\times14=490$, and $14\times6=84$, none of which is a multiple of $210$.

Now let's show that we can't have $n=pqr$ with $p,q,r$ all prime. If we did, we'd have for each pair of non-adjacent numbers at least one of the number would be divisible by at least two of the primes. Then the numbers adjacent to the two-prime number couldn't be divisible by the third prime. But then their product wouldn't be divisible by the third prime, so not divisible by $n$, contradiction.

Similar reasoning shows we can't have $n=pq$ or $n=p$ for primes $p,q$, so, if $n$ is squarefree, it must have at least four distinct prime divisors, hence, must be at least $210$. So to finish we just have to eliminate the possibility that $n$ has three or fewer distinct prime factors, and is not squarefree.

This case is a bit messier, and I have not written up a complete proof.

Comment: Ok that's a great solution for 4. Thank You for that. But for nine then, would the smallest n just be the product of the first 9 prime numbers?

Comment: I think the same arguments should go through.

Comment: Can you show what nine would look like when you get a chance!